# How to get a select drop-down element to autoselect the first option?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My select drop-down element contains the correct options, but on first load there is no default option selected. That means the drop-down appears blank. How can I ensure the first option in the list is selected WITHOUT resorting to hardcoded `selected` attribute because the data is actually dynamically loaded from a database.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkz17j9m/) and same below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
   return {
    Form: {
     TypeID: null
    }
   }
      }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<form>
    <li>
     <label for="Category">Category:</label>
     <select id="Category" name="Category" v-model.number="Form.TypeID">
      <option value="3">Vegetable</option>
      <option value="1">Bread</option>
      <option value="2">Dairy</option>
     </select>
    </li>
</form>

</div>
```

If I change the `Form: { TypeID: null }` code to `Form: { TypeID: 1 }` then `Bread` appears selected as default.

So given the above I thought I should try to get the first option in the select element like such:

```
Form: {
        TypeID: document.querySelector("#Category").selectedIndex = 0,
    }
```

But if I do that then I get an error along the lines of `[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedIndex' of null"`

Comment: you might be able to just add in `selected` on the option you want       `<option value="3" selected>Vegetable</option>`

Comment: @RyanDeckard I can't because the options are not hardcoded - they're loaded dynamically

Comment: Actually the **error** (warning) you get is because you refer to a **DOM** element that doesn't exist when the `Form.TypeID` data attribute is set. The `data` attributes are initiated **before the DOM** in **Vue**, so the visuals can display the data you want. **Vue lifecycle**: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly set it in `Form.TypeID`.

HTML `selected` attribute won't work as it is overwritten by **Vue**'s `v-model`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      Form: {
        TypeID: 3
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form>
    <li>
      <label for="Category">Category:</label>
      <select id="Category" name="Category" v-model.number="Form.TypeID">
        <option value="3">Vegetable</option>
        <option value="1">Bread</option>
        <option value="2">Dairy</option>
      </select>
    </li>
  </form>

</div>
```

#### A bit other way:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      Form: {
        TypeID: null
      },
      selectOptions: [{
          text: 'Vegetable',
          val: 3
        },
        {
          text: 'Bread',
          val: 1
        },
        {
          text: 'Dairy',
          val: 2
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // setting the default selected option on the form
    // by picking the first item in the selectOptions
    // data attribute
    this.Form.TypeID = this.selectOptions[0].val
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form>
    <li>
      <label for="Category">Category:</label>
      <select id="Category" name="Category" v-model.number="Form.TypeID">
        <option v-for="(item, i) in selectOptions" :key="i" :value="item.val">
          {{ item.text }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </li>
  </form>

</div>
```

With **Vue** you should not rely on **DOM** elements - only as a last resort. Create the data structure as `data`, `computed`, or anything and only render that data structure in the **DOM**.

Comment: But the problem is that `3` may not always be an option value. Sometimes there may only be `1` or `2` available.

Comment: Don't worry about that - that's why there are **lifecycle hooks** - I'll update my last example with that

Comment: @volumeone My answer is updated according to the comment before - inserted a setup function in the `mounted()` lifecycle hook in my last example

Comment: Very nice, I adapted it for my requirements and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work for me.
you can get the first `option` element and pass its value to TypeID to select it.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
   return {
    Form: {
     TypeID: document.querySelector("#Category option:first-of-type").value
    }
   }
      }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<form>
    <li>
     <label for="Category">Category:</label>
     <select id="Category" name="Category" v-model.number="Form.TypeID">
      <option value="3">Vegetable</option>
      <option value="1">Bread</option>
      <option value="2">Dairy</option>
     </select>
    </li>
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: You're right it works in the code fiddle but when I try it for real in my app I get an error saying `[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"`

Comment: try adding the null check for `document.querySelector("#Category option:first-of-type")` selector... like `TypeID: document.querySelector("#Category option:first-of-type") ? document.querySelector("#Category option:first-of-type").value : null`

Comment: Tried that as well but then it just goes back to selecting blank!

Comment: @AneesIjaz the problem is that it's going to be always `null` and won't update - the **DOM element** doesn't exist at the time of setting the `data` attribute. I added a comment to OP's question with a bit more information on this.

Comment: It does work when the DOM element is available before the data exists which was also very helpful when the items were hardcoded.